# Check how many pages are included in a multi-page image file with GraphicsMagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

Is there a way to determine in advance how many pages are included in a multi page tif image with GraphicsMagick ?
I know I can select the first page in this way : `image.tif[0]`, and probably iterating the array until the command fail will return the last image, but I don't think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a numbered list of the pages with

```
gm identify image.tif
```

and look at the last line, or count the lines.  The images are numbered 0 thru N -1.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too late to answer.

I think it is not possible to get the page count beforehand, not even with libtiff.
However, you can avoid the trial and error by using Magick::readImages:

```
// Magick++
std::vector<Magic::Image> images;
Magick::readImages(&images, "multipage.tif");
```